# python xlrd fetch first row value

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, import-from-excel

I am using xlrd with python to pull excel data everything is fine and data pulling is fine but the code fetching last row data only.

**Here is my Excel**

```
+-------------------+------------+------------------------+
| polling_station_1 | Cairo      | 7734                   |
+-------------------+------------+------------------------+
| polling_station_2 | Giza       | 13332                  |
+-------------------+------------+------------------------+
| polling_station_3 | Alexandria | 10901                  |
+-------------------+------------+------------------------+
```

**Here is my Code**

```
import xlrd

excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook("teacher.xlsx")
sheet1= excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('parents')

for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):        
      row = sheet1.row_slice(i)        
      Gname = row[0].value        
      Fname = row[1].value        
      Lname = row[2].value

print Gname
print Fname
print Lname
```

**And the Result**

```
polling_station_3  
Alexandria 
10901
```

which is the last Row but i want data from first row
**Note : Changed Range still last row showing up.**

Anyone Please Figure out

Comment: Your Gname, Fname, Lname variables contain the last row because they are accessed *after* the for loop has finished iterating over all the rows. Try moving your print statements inside the loop and see for yourself.

Comment: please tell me a example so i cant fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook("teacher.xlsx")
sheet1= excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('parents')
row = sheet1.row(0)  # 1st row
```

**If print Row Output will be**

```
[text:u'polling_station_1', text:u'cairo', text:u'7734']
```

**Now slice it or get value one by one**

```
Gname = row[0].value        
Fname = row[1].value        
Lname = row[2].value

print Gname
print Fname
print Lname
```

**Now Result will be**

```
olling_station_3 
Alexandria 
10901
```

**If want to change row**

```
row = sheet1.row(0)  # change row(0) Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook("teacher.xlsx")
sheet1= excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('parents')

for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):        
    row = sheet1.row_slice(i)        
    Gname = row[0].value        
    Fname = row[1].value        
    Lname = row[2].value

# these are outside the for loop so only printed for last row
print Gname
print Fname
print Lname

    # indent them to here and they will be printed for all rows
    print Gname
    print Fname
    print Lname
```

Comment: Thanx @Steve, i figured out what was the isse. BTW thanx for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have a coding issue.  By changing the print statements, you can see the results.

```
import xlrd

excel_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook("teacher.xlsx")
sheet1= excel_sheet.sheet_by_name('parents')

for i in range(0, sheet1.nrows):        
    row = sheet1.row_slice(i)        
    Gname = row[0].value        
    Fname = row[1].value        
    Lname = row[2].value

    print Gname
    print Fname
    print Lname
```

You're iterating through the rows and only printing the final result currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate over the row, leave it to the `xlrd` module use the sheet method [`sheet.row_value(index)`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.row_values) to get the values directly. Note that it's zero indexed.